# How to find shortest path traveled given a set of must pass points in C?

Tags: c, struct, coordinates, shortest-path, dijkstra

So I have a "layout" of a map, structured as shown below:

```
    a--(2)--b--(2)--c
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    d       e       f
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    g       h       i
    |       |       |
   (1)     (1)     (1)
    |       |       |
    j--(2)--k--(2)--l
```

the letters (a,b,c,d...etc) represent location points. The numbers in between two letters represent the distance between those two points. For example, the distance between point "a" and point "b" is 2 and the distance between point "a" and point "d" is 1.

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate the shortest path possible from a given start point, a set of must pass points, and then going back to the start point. So for example, given the start point being point "a", and me needing to go to points "b", "e", and "c", the most optimal path I can take would be `a -> b -> c -> b -> e -> b -> a` with a total distance traveled of 10 units. Another path I could take is `a -> b -> e -> b -> c -> b -> a` which is the same distance (10 units).

In my code, I've stored each point, along with their respective distances in relation to other points, in a struct. Like this:

```
struct stopPoints {
    int  weights[10];
    char connectingPoints[10];
    int startBool;
};
```

I've stored the info of each point into a string, showing the points that it's connected to, along with it's weight:

```
char str[12][100] = {
    "a = S, 2.b, 1.d",
    "b = 2.a, 1.e",
    "c = 2.b, 1.f",
    "d = 1.a, 1.g",
    "e = 1.h, 1.b",
    "f = 1.i, 1.c",
    "g = 1.j, 1.d",
    "h = 1.k, 1.e",
    "i = 1.l, 1.f",
    "j = 1.g, 2.k",
    "k = 2.j, 1.h, 2.l",
    "l = 2.k, 1.i"
};
```

Note: I've been successful in separating each point and storing all the info into their own separate structs. Also, notice how point "a" has the letter S in it. This is to indicate that it's the starting point (and also the end point).

I've been researching some path finding algorithms and the best option so far that I think could be applicable to this situation is Dijkstra's algorithm. The only problem is that I have points that aren't connected at all, like point "d" and "e", and the fact that I also need to go to certain points (must pass points), so implementing that would be somewhat difficult. I only need the shortest path starting from the starting point, going to the must pass points, and returning back to the starting point.

How should I go about starting this? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you start with a google for the Traveling Salesman Problem, and learn about the Nearest Neighbor First algorithm

Comment: @EvilTeach thanks! I didn't know about the Nearest Neighbor First algorithm. I've already looked into the TSP algorithm but I don't think that would apply because I don't need to traverse through every single point of my given layout.